# How can I calculate $(4A^{-1} - A^3)^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $E= \begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$ and let $A=\begin{bmatrix}
I & 0 & 0 \\
0 & E & I \\
0 & I & -E
\end{bmatrix}$.

How can I calculate $(4A^{-1} - A^3)^n$ for some integer $n$?

Comment: Hint: compute $B^2$ for $B=\begin{bmatrix}E & I \\ I & -E\end{bmatrix}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do block multiplication, calling
$$
F=\begin{bmatrix} E & I \\ I & -E \end{bmatrix}
$$
you see that
$$
A^k=\begin{bmatrix} I & 0 \\ 0 & F^k \end{bmatrix}
$$
for *any* integer $k$, including $-1$.

Thus you need to compute
$$
F^3=\begin{bmatrix} (E^2+I)E & E^2+I \\ E^2+I & -(E^2+I)E \end{bmatrix}
$$
and, with block reduction,
$$
F^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} (E^2+I)^{-1}E & (E^2+I)^{-1} \\ (E^2+I)^{-1} & -(E^2+I)^{-1}E \end{bmatrix}
$$
The key is thus $E^2=I$.

Comment: Thank you so much!